# How can I Sum for each month 4 month back including itself? (SQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql

Im braking my head to solve this problem, I hope you guys. Can help me.
So I have this Table:

| Date | Total |
| --- | --- |
| 2021/01/01 | 10000 |
| 2021/02/01 | 20000 |
| 2021/03/01 | 30000 |
| 2021/04/01 | 30000 |
| 2021/05/01 | 10000 |
| 2021/06/01 | 20000 |
| 2021/07/01 | 30000 |
| 2021/08/01 | 30000. |
| 2021/09/01 | 10000 |
| 2021/010/01 | 20000 |
| 2021/011/01 | 30000 |
| 2021/12/01 | 30000. |

"

and I need to calculate for each month the sum of 4 month before total (including itself).
Thanks for the help

Comment: Is every month always guaranteed to be present (so just sum the preceding 4 ***rows***) or do you require the answer to check if the 4th row preceding is actually within the last 4 months?

Comment: Every month is always present. What is the syntax for this preceding function?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT Date, SUM(Total) OVER (ORDER BY Date RANGE INTERVAL '4' MONTH
PRECEDING) FROM tbl;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use windowed/analytic functions.

```
SUM(total) OVER (ORDER BY date
             ROWS BETWEEN 3 PRECEDING
                      AND CURRENT_ROW
           )
              AS total_4months
```